# NoClassDefFoundError on Glassfish after deploying war

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, glassfish, war

I am developing small web application using netbeans and maven.

Project consists of three modules:

prychadmin (this is main module)

travel

interfaces

It has to be divided like that because two latter modules are also used elsewhere. I pack everything into a war file (modules travel and interfaces included in WEB-INF/lib) and try deploying to glassfish (tried deploying via netbeans and also manually) and I get NoClassDefFoundError on one of the classes included in travel module.

```
RuntimeException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: chore/gry/prych/map/LocationImpl
```

I was searching for few days for the solution and one source told me to modify MANIFEST.MF so it now looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: user
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_26
Class-Path: travel-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar log4j-1.2.16.jar interfaces-1.0-SN
 APSHOT.jar
```

but it didn't help.

I also tried deploying it to tomcat, but it didn't work also so it must be my stupid mistake in war file.

Does anyone have any ideas?

here's my prychadimn project pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>prych</artifactId>
    <groupId>chore.gry</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>chore.gry.prych</groupId>
<artifactId>prychadmin</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>prychadmin Java EE 6 Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net2</id>
        <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>apache</id>
        <name>Apache</name>
        <url>http://ftp.cica.es/mirrors/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>chore.gry.prych</groupId>
        <artifactId>travel</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-alpha-2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>

                            <copy todir="src\main\webapp\chore\gry\prych\prychadmin\mapa">
                                <fileset dir="target\classes\chore\gry\prych\prychadmin\mapa"/>
                            </copy>


                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>prychadmin</finalName>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>endorsed</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>sun.boot.class.path</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- javaee6 contains upgrades of APIs contained within the JDK itself.
                        As such these need to be placed on the bootclasspath, rather than classpath of the
                        compiler.
                        If you don't make use of these new updated API, you can delete the profile.
                        On non-SUN jdk, you will need to create a similar profile for your jdk, with the similar property as sun.boot.class.path in Sun's JDK.-->
                        <compilerArguments>
                            <bootclasspath>${settings.localRepository}/javax/javaee-endorsed-api/6.0/javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar${path.separator}${sun.boot.class.path}</bootclasspath>
                        </compilerArguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>javax</groupId>
                            <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                            <version>6.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
</project>
```

My environment:

Windows 7

Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Netbeans 7.2

JDK 1.6.0_26

Maven 3.0.3

**EDIT1**
Here's my package tree:

```
-   index.jsp
-
+---chore
-   L---gry
-       L---prych
-           L---prychadmin
-               L---mapa
-                       DBConnector.class
-                       Location.class
-                       ....
-                       PathsEditorPanel.class
-
+---css
-       prych.css
-
+---lib
-       travel-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
-
+---META-INF
-   -   context.xml
-   -   MANIFEST.MF
-   -
-   +---maven
-   -   L---chore.gry.prych
-   -       L---prychadmin
-   -               pom.properties
-   -               pom.xml
-   -
-   L---services
-           java.sql.Driver
-
+---org
-   L---postgresql
-       -   Driver$1.class
-       -   Driver$ConnectThread.class
-       -   ...
-               RecoveredXid.class
-
L---WEB-INF
    +---classes
    -   L---chore
    -       L---gry
    -           L---prych
    -               L---prychadmin
    -                   -   Starter.class
    -                   -
    -                   L---mapa
    -                           DBConnector.class
    -                           LocationAdmin.class
    -                           ...
    -                           PathsEditorPanel.class
    -
    L---lib
        interfaces-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
        log4j-1.2.16.jar
        travel-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar    <-- this is the one that has LocationImpl.class
```

There's also one strange this I have notices, it might as well have no impact on the problem. In folder *chore* in main direction are not only classes from my main module but also two classes (interfaces actually) from second of the two libraries.

Comment: please provide error details. These three modules you said, are all different aplications OR packages ?

Comment: I added exact error message I get to description. Those three modules are different packages, only prychadmin is application, other two are simple jars with classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding your application dependent jar files two domains ext (domain1/lib/ext) directory.

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work, maybe I should restart something? I looked at glassfish web admin tool but it shows nothing under Libraries for this application

Comment: try by removing your GlassFish. Remove all the contents from domain->deploy and domain->generated and domain->eclipse apps and domain->osgi cache directory.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to modify your manifest file. From the error message, it seems the missing class is the one from your main module. Can you ensure that the class exist in WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: This class is in .jar package in lib directory, I triple-checked this. Well, I could copy .class file to classes folder but I see no point, I want to find out why it doesn't work designed way, with .jar in lib, not use questionable workarounds. Of course, if everything fails I'll use this workaround, but I would very much like to do it the right way.

Comment: If you say that it doesn't work on tomcat, clearly the structure is not right. Can you lay out the directory structure within the war file? Particularly with regard to the class that is not found

Comment: I added it to problem description

Comment: Your war structure doesn't seems right. Why don't you manually try to clean them up first and the try using tomcat? It looks so messy.

Comment: What doesn't seems right exactly, what should I remove in your opinion? This war is generated using maven-war-plugin as you can see in pom.xml above.

Comment: All classes have to be within WEB-INF/classes directory, and all jar files have to be within WEB-INF/lib directory.